# If $Y$ ~ $geo(1-\theta)$, what's a ML estimator for $\theta$?

Tags: probability, self-study, estimation, maximum-likelihood, geometric-distribution

Suppose we have $Y$ ~ $geo(1-\theta)$ for $\theta \in (0,1)$.

That is the pdf of $Y$ is given by $\theta^{k-1}(1-\theta).$

Formally, from what I understand the ML estimator for $1-\theta$ comes out to be $\frac{Y-1}{Y}$. But in a practice quiz a question which asks for the ML estimator for $\theta$ has the answer as $\frac{Y-1}{Y}$.

Which is correct, should't the ML estimator for $\theta$ be $1-\frac{Y-1}{Y} = \frac{1}{Y}$?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Please tell us precisely what you mean by "$geo(1-\theta)$". Then compare that to what the quiz assumes this means.

Comment: @whuber is that more clear? the practice quiz assumes just that. My question is simple - what's the correct ML estimator for $\theta$?

Comment: @whuber, I think if this is an introductory statistics course, that it's more than likely safe to assume that $geo(1−\theta)$ is a geometric distribution with parameter $1−\theta$. I can't think of any other distributions that would coincide with this notation for MLE in an into course.

Comment: @Mariah The answer I get for the parameter estimate is $\frac{(\sum k_i) -n}{\sum k_i}$. Then for $1- \theta$ the estimate is  $-\frac{n}{\sum k_i}$. Once the question is re-opened I can show how it's derived.

Comment: @Analyst1 Have you considered the possibility that it refers to a geometric distribution with parameter $\theta$?  This appears to be a question about the meaning of the notation and not about any facts of probability or statistics, so it is essential that the notation be unambiguously defined.

Comment: @whuber, I don't think so.  The question seems to be about the MLE for $\theta$.  The question asks nothing about notation unless I'm misunderstanding something.  I think Dole answered it properly below.  But I agree, it couldn't hurt for the notation to be clarified.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the geo distribution where the probability of success for each trial is $1-\theta$.

The MLH estimate can be derived as

$$f_{x1...xn}(x_1...x_n)=\prod \theta^{k_i-1}(1-\theta)$$

$$=\theta^{\sum{k_i-1}}(1-\theta)^n$$

$${(\sum{k_i-1})} log(\theta)+nlog(1-\theta) \ \ \ \ \ \ \  || log$$

$$\frac{{(\sum{k_i-1})}}\theta)-\frac{n}{1-\theta}=0 \ \ \ \ ||derivative=0$$

$${(\sum{k_i-1})}(1-\theta) -n \theta=0$$

$$\sum k_i -n-\theta\sum k_i+n\theta  -n\theta=0$$

$$\hat \theta =\frac {\sum k_i-n}{\sum k_i}$$

So then:

$$\hat {1-\theta} =\frac {n}{\sum k_i}$$

Which is also the MLH estimate for $geo(\theta)$.